# How to see the web.xml is read in my Web project

Tags: java, html, web-services, tomcat, dynamic

I wrote a basic Hello World we dynamic project with the apache server installed with it.

My directory structure is,
[image]

Web.xml content is,

```
  <display-name>hello</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.html</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
```

hello.html is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!!
</body>
</html>
```

After starting my apache, I'm trying to access the URL,
http://localhost:8080/hello.html  
Getting error as : **HTTP Status 404** - /hello.html 
Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no hello.xml in your project directory. The correct URL should be http://localhost:8080/hello.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think you need to add the name of your project in the url:

http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/

or http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/hello.html

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to into a deeper directory.

http://localhost:8080/WebContent/hello.html

The above one should work I think :)

Comment: Still same 404 error. BTW, why do we need to include WebContent?

Comment: You need to basically open up every folder up to the hello.xml directory.

Comment: Because the program cant see what is in these Folders, it only sees what is in the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is from other applications using the port 8080, check if any program else on same port.